# Visual Studio 2012 Prerequisites: Fatal error during installation

Tags: visual-studio-2012

What is causing this error to occur during the installation of Visual Studio 2012?

[image: What is causing this error to occur during the installation of Visual Studio 2012?]

Comment: Hard to tell.  Did you have a look at the log file?  (Just click on that second link in the dialog.)  You'll probably quickly see what's wrong near the end of that file, or it at least will give you something to search for.

Comment: if you are using win 7 have you installed service park 1 ?

Comment: i had the same issue but it turns out my downloaded installer was incomplete. so make sure you dont have corrupted file.

Comment: Use either the Web installer or the offline installer from [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30654).

Answer (score -1):

Download following from internet and install before start installing VS2012 then it will not show any error

- Visual Studio 2012 Update 1 - Online install from link provided on top of document
- Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2012
- Team Explorer Everywhere for TFS 2012 with Update 1
- .NET 4.5
- Agents for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Update 1
- IntelliTrace Collector for Visual Studio
- Feedback Client for TFS  - Online install from link provided on top of document
- C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 1
- Visual Studio 2012 Shell
- Visual Studio 2012 SDK